# Is there a way to position the navigation arrows above and below the slides when using the vertical direction option with sliderjs in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, swiper.js

I'm using SliderJS to create a swiping feed like interface in a React app. I want the swiping to go up down / top to bottom vs. left to right. Swiper gives a nice verical option for doing this like so

```
  <Swiper
     navigation={true}
     direction={"vertical"}
     onSlideChange={() => console.log("slide change")}>
```

The problem is that the left and right navigation chevrons are automatically and absolutely placed.

[image: arrow example]

[This github issue gives some hacky CSS](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/3592) but it only works for the bottom arrow.

[image]

Because of the automatic absolute position of these arrows, I can't get the top one to appear above my slide content. Is there some way to do this sort of UI without getting so hacky?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was accidentally putting my navigation divs inside the `<Swiper>` element. I put them out side of it and I was much more easily able to position them

```
</Swiper>
    <div className="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div className="swiper-button-next"></div>
```

and

```
   .swiper-button-prev {
      left: 63% !important;
      top: 40% !important;
      transform: rotate(90deg);
      transform-origin: left center;
    }
    .swiper-button-next {
      left: 63% !important;
      bottom: 49% !important;
      transform: rotate(90deg);
      transform-origin: left center;

    }
```